# Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class but imports seem good

Tags: java, hibernate

Here are my entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "user_uuid")
    private UUID id;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String username;

    private String password;
}
```

The User table is used by Spring Security to check the logged in user.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "seller")
public class Seller {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "seller_uuid")
    private UUID id;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "seller_user",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "seller_uuid"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "users_uuid"))
    private Set<User> users;
}
```

But here is the error I get at launch:

```
Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: seller.modele.entity.Seller.users[user.model.entity.User]
```

I checked, I use the correct imports (Seller/User and javax.persistence.*)

Answer (score 0):

I guess that your (Spring?) application does not scan the `user.model.entity` package or you didn't list the fully qualified name of the class in your persistence.xml. In case of Spring, you will have to use e.g. `@EntityScan("*")` or `@EntityScan({"seller.modele.entity.*", "user.model.entity.*"})` or if you don't use that, you will probably have to add `<class>user.model.entity.User</class>` to your persistence.xml along where your other classes are listed.